# Azure Backup cannot connect to App Service PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, azure, web-config, azure-web-app-service

I have an app created in App Service. As a db I use Azure Database for PostgreSQL server.

Recently I configured Backups for this app through the built-in App Service Backup functionality. But each backups fails with message

`Error occurred while connecting to the database <db_name> on server <server>: 28P01: password authentication failed for user "<user>"`

In the backup configuration the connections string is set to `defaultConnection`. I checked in the 'Application settings' panel and string `defaultConnection` looks fine. Also, when I take values from the string and use them via terminal and `psql` it connects properly. So what can be the issue here?

Maybe the fact that I have chars like %, #, ^, !, *, $ in the password can be problematic?

Best Regards,
Konrad

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to launch the backup feature. I have created a different connection string with a different user (the same user as the database connection uses), and not the azure default one. As the access should not be a problem (I've tested the default user using `psql`, probably the issue was with the password containing "fancy" special characters.

Fortunately, using another user the backups are generated.